# How do you earn the Advanced Stealth and Advanced Close Combat PEC Challenges?

Tags: splinter-cell-conviction

Splinter Cell Conviction has Prepare and Execute (P.E.C.) Challenges that reward players for certain actions such as the following.

- **Advanced Stealth:**
  Complete a level without being spotted and without retrying.
- **Advanced Close Combat:**
  Complete a level without firing a single shot and without retrying.

How did you complete these and what are the definitions for *"level"* and *"retrying?"*

- Is a level an entire single player chapter and does a Deniable Ops run count?
- Does dying and restarting count as "retrying?"
- Does using a gadget make you lose Advanced Close Combat?

I'd hate to keep trying the wrong way (either to keep going to the main menu when not needed, or to miss the requirements because I restarted the wrong way).

Comment: Console or PC?  Some of these you can "cheese" with a second controller in split screen, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Good questions +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a FAQ [on IGN...](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/108/1082367p1.html)

> **Advanced Close Combat** - Complete an entire scene (a whole level)
>   without manually shooting a firearm and without retrying. Basically,
>   use only hand-to-hand attacks and gadgets. (The animation where your
>   character grabs and then shoots the victim up close is okay. Just
>   don't press the Fire Button, and don't press the Execute Button,
>   although you may mark enemies to keep track of them. For an easier
>   time, do this at a level like Scene 2 (Kobin's Mansion) on the Rookie
>   difficulty setting.

---

> **Advanced Stealth** - Complete an entire level without getting detected,
>   without coming into bodily contact with any enemy, and without
>   retrying. For an easier time, do this in the cooperative hunter mode,
>   at the St. Petersburg Banya on the Rookie difficulty setting, and have
>   the teammate kill all the enemies, while your character hangs back.
>   The character attempting this challenge can still throw out explosives
>   from dark areas to help, but he shouldn't do so if things are too
>   risky.

Hope this helps.

Comment: From what I remember, 'retrying' would be considered: reloading from a checkpoint [due to death, failure, etc]

Answer (score 0):

A Couple of additional notes.

- An entire Map (all zones) on a Deniable Ops Hunter game is considered one level.
- In **Advanced Close Combat**, detection is permitted (although way harder when the enemy has doubled numbers with weapons hot, in Deniable Ops/Hunter)
- For both of these PEC Challenges, In all play modes It's neccessary to "Return To Lobby" or "Main Menu" and replay from the beginning of the Map/Level, if you die or fire a shot, are detected etc. Check the Attempts number in the end of zone stats, if it's not 1, you won't get the award.
- All gadgets (EMP Grenades, Portable EMP, Flashbangs, Remote Mines, Frag Grenades) do not count as shots fired in **Advanced Close Combat**.

Answer (score -1):

You can complete both very easily by doing the Thrid Echelon. From the start in the carpark, plant lots of C4 - you will need to kill two people (use death from above on both). Once you've made it into the lift it will cut to a cutscene - that should be challenges completed.